# How to show the differential form $\nu$ satisfies $\nu(v_1, \ldots, v_n)=\det(a_{ij})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra

In $\mathbb R^n$ consider the differential form $\nu$ satisfying $\nu(e_1, \ldots, e_n)=1$. For every $i=1, \ldots, n$ consider the vector  $\displaystyle v_i=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} e_j$. How to show $\nu(v_1, \ldots, v_n)=\det(a_{ij})$? I can see it is true, but I can't argue why that is true..

I guess I should use the relation $$f^*\omega=\det(df)dx_1\wedge \ldots \wedge dx_n,$$ where $f:\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow \mathbb R^n$, $f=(f_1, \ldots, f_n)$, $y_i=f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $\omega=dy_1\wedge \ldots \wedge dy_n$. Using this, given $v_i=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} e_j$, I defined $f:\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow \mathbb R^n$, $f=(f_1, \ldots, f_n)$, setting $$f_i(x_1, \ldots, x_n)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j.$$

Then $\partial_j f_i=a_{ij}$ hence $$(f^*\omega)(e_1, \ldots, e_n)=\det(a_{ij})dx_1\wedge \ldots \wedge dx_n(e_1, \ldots, e_n)=\det(a_{ij}).$$
So the problem amounts showing $(f^*\omega)(e_1, \ldots, e_n)=\nu(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$, but still I can't do that.

Can anyone give me some hint?

**Obs:**

**(i)** I still don't know $\displaystyle\det(a_{ij})=\sum_{\sigma} \textrm{sign}(\sigma) a_{1\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{n\sigma(n)}$.

**(ii)** $(f^*\omega)(v_1, \ldots, v_n)=\omega(df(v_1), \ldots, df(v_n))$ (in simplified notation, i.e., ommiting the point the form came from).

Comment: 1) What is the definition of $f^\ast \omega$?
2) What is the relation between the $v_j$ and the $e_k$?

Comment: A added the definition of $f^*\omega$ and the relation between $v_j$ and $e_k$ is $v_i=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} e_j$.

Comment: So, $(f^\ast\omega)(e_1,\dotsc,e_n) = \omega(df(e_1),\dotsc,df(e_n))$. Given that $f$ is a linear transformation, what is $df$?

Comment: df is the Jacobian of $f$. I did this calculation and $\omega(df(e_1), \ldots, df(e_n))=\det(a_{ij})$. I'm starting to believe there is no direct way to show $(f^*\omega)(e_1, \ldots, e_n)=\nu(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$.

Comment: Of course there is. What is $df$ if $f$ is a linear transformation (and why?), and what, therefore, is $df(e_k)$?

Comment: Well, if $f$ is a linear transformation $df=f$ hence $df(e_k)=f(e_k)=(a_{1k}, \ldots, a_{nk})$.

Comment: And how does $df(e_k)$ therefore relate to $v_k$?

Comment: $df(e_k)$ gives the coefficients of $v_k$..

Comment: Well, OK, $df(e_k)$ is a vector; what does it look like as a linear combination of the basis vectors $e_j$, and what other vector does that linear combination remind you of?

Comment: We have $df(e_k)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{jk}e_j=v_k$.

Comment: Now, can you use the fact that $\nu = dx^1 \wedge \cdots dx^n$?

Comment: Yes, I can. Thanks!

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Let's suppose I couldn't use $\nu=dx^1\wedge\ldots\wedge dx_n$, could I still get to the same conclusion? The problem is that $\nu=dx_1\wedge\ldots \wedge dx_n$ is what I should show in part $(b)$ of this problem.

Comment: What definition of the determinant do you have at your disposal anyway? Depending on an author's taste, you can first define it in terms of the cofactor expansion along your favourite row or column, or as the unique $n$-linear form etc. etc. etc., or as the induced linear transformation on the $1$-dimensional vector space $\wedge^n \mathbb{R}^n$, which is therefore a constant (the determinant) times the identity.